# Error:Execution failed for task, duplicate entry

Tags: java, android

I have this error message:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllReleaseClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

**My build gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.doldurkazan.umutbahadir.sonolsun"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4-with-sources.jar')
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
}
```

Let me know how to resolve the issue.

Comment: try removing support-v4 from ksoap2 lib

Answer (score 1):

This should hopefully work.... Make sure you remove the jar files from the libs folder as they will cause you problems.  This now fetches the latest versions from maven

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doldurkazan.umutbahadir.sonolsun"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0"
        compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
        compile group: 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader', name: 'universal-image-loader', version: '1.9.5'
        compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.6.0'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        repositories {
            maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/ksoap2-android-releases' }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

instead of including the v4 support libraries the same way as you are adding appcompat???  This is a guaranteed way to create errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.doldurkazan.umutbahadir.sonolsun"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.8.jar')
        compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.4-with-sources.jar')
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


        compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

you may or may not need to add

```
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1"
```

All versions of the support libraries in use need to match, so you can mix a v23 and a v22 in the same project.

Comment: i try this. but no change

Comment: Did you do a full clean and build?

Comment: You might also try using 

compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

instead of using a jar file.  You will need to delete the jar files from your libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

try removing this

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

code and clean your project.it may help